# Hibernate saveOrUpdate() adds new etities in related tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am currently learning hibernate and created a simple database that is simulating a library:

I got 3 classes: Book, Customer, Order:

```
@Entity
public class Book
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private int ISBN;
    private String name;
    private String autorName;
    private double price;
//Getters setters etc...
}


@Entity
public class Customer
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String city;
//Getters setters etc...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_order")
public class Order
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private Date date;
    private String status;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn
    private List<Book> books;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Customer customer;
//Getters setters etc...
}
```

When I try to change some order by saveOrUpdate() (eg. change the book that customer ordered) I create new instance of Order and I pass it to saveOrUpdate() method:

```
 Order o = new Order(Date.valueOf("2019-06-01"),"old",bookslist.subList(2,3), customerslist.get(0));
 o.setId(1);
 session.saveOrUpdate(o);
```

It does not only change values in table order, but it also create new entities in table book and table Customers. I guess it is like this because i put the list of books and customer instace created in the main method.

So what instance of Order object shall be passed into the saveOrUpdate() method to only change the values in table Order to already existing values from database?

Comment: You would put existing books/customers, identified by an existing ID. Usually obtained by querying the database using Hibernate, in one way or another (get(), load(), query(), etc.). Note that you really should learn the standard JPA API rather than the old, proprietary Hibernate API.

Comment: Why do you think the Hibernate API is "old, proprietary"?

Comment: Because it was designed a long time ago (hence old), before the better JPA API was designed, not repeating the design mistakes done in the original design, and because i can only be used with Hibernate (hence proprietary), whereas the JPA API van be used with any JPA implementation, and is the basis for higher-leven APIs such as spring-data-jpa.

Comment: @JBNizet Thaks a lot for your answer. I would like to clarify if I understand this correctly:

- The JPA is specification that defines API for the object-relational mappings and managing persistent objects.
-The Hibernate is implementation of JPA (because it only provides the interafaces)
-The JPA API is another implementation of JPA

Is that correct?

Comment: No. JPA is a specification, which defines an API (EntityManager, etc.), and a set of standard behaviors. Hibernate is an implementation of that specification. It provides implementations for the interfaces and behaviors defines in JPA.

Comment: Hmm... But to use JPA i need an implementation of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194336/discussion-between-elrok-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: Yes. Indeed. And as I said, Hibernate is an implementation of JPA.